# Azure Resource Group Deployment is failing

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-resource-group

My release pipeline fails on task AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2 with error:

> Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern

Here is the yaml code:

```
       steps:

      - download: build
        #artifact: function, arm

      - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
        displayName: 'Perform Resource Deployment'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(qaSubscription)
          action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
          resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroup)
          location: $(location)
          templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
          csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm/azuredeploy.json'
          csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
          deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

I don't understand what may be wrong here...

Comment: Well, it says the template file (arm/azuredeploy.json) isn't there. Sounds plausible, especially if your pipeline hasn't checked out any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add "build/" to the path:

```
csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build/arm/azuredeploy.json'
```